# Linux Azure VM Not Accessible after creating via Powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, ssh

I am trying to deploy a Linux Virtual Machine on Azure using the following Powershell Command. I am also assigning a Reserved Public IPv4 address to the Virtual Machine.

The code is as below -

```
 New-AzureVMConfig -Name $blogname -InstanceSize Small -ImageName "b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubunt

 u-15.04-Snappy-core-amd64-stable-201509241855-1-en-us-30GB" | Add-    AzureProvisioningConfig 
 -Linux -LinuxUser $user -Password $password | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $blogServiceName 
 -ReservedIPName "BlogVMIP" -Location "East US"
```

Whenever I try to connect to the Virtual Machine (Public Port is `64678` for SSH), I get the following error -

```
debug1: Connecting to XXX.cloudapp.net [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 64678.
debug1: connect to address XX.XX.XX.XX port 64678: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host XXX.cloudapp.net port 64678: Connection refused
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I also checked the portal and according to it, there is an SSH endpoint. And yes, I am using the correct credentials.

Thanks!

-Pranav

Comment: Check the endpoints are added correctly

Comment: @Aatif - Like I said, the endpoints are correctly configured.